# jQuery stop function from being called when its already being called by other event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to call a function in two ways: either way, when the function is called it should not allow the other one to call the method

Here `renameFolder` is called in two places: first on focus out and second when enter is being pressed.

The problem is that when enter is pressed it calls the function 2 times 1 for enter being pressed and second for focus out as well.

Following is my jsfiddle example : https://jsfiddle.net/tzx0ojLk/12/

and following is my code:

```
$('#rename').click(function () {

        //delete previous popup-menu if exists
        removeMenu();

        var folder = e.target.id;
        var folderId = $("#" + folder).attr("id");
        var folderName = $('#' + folder).parent().parent().children('.bd-title').text().trim();

        $('#' + folder).parent().parent().children('.bd-title').replaceWith('<textarea class="bd-folder-title-input" oninput="this.style.height = `1px`;this.style.height = (10+this.scrollHeight)+`px`;"  onfocusout="renameFolder()" maxlength="50" cols="10">' + folderName + '</textarea>');
        $('textarea').focus();
        $('textarea').select();
        $("textarea").keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
                // alert(e);
                // $('textarea').trigger( "focusout" );
                // console.log(e);
                // e.trigger('focusout');
                // $('#' + folder).parent().parent().children('.bd-folder-title-input').trigger( "focusout" );
                $('body').focus();
                // console.log($(e.currentTarget));
                $('.bd-folder-title-input').trigger('focusout');
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add focusout listner after you call focus and select:

```
$('#rename').click(function() {

  //delete previous popup-menu if exists

  var folder = 1;
  //alert(folder);
  var folderId = $("#" + folder).attr("id");
  var folderName = $('#' + folder).parent().parent().children('.bd-title').text().trim();

  $('#' + folder).parent().parent().children('.bd-title').replaceWith('<textarea class="bd-folder-title-input" oninput="this.style.height = `1px`;this.style.height = (10+this.scrollHeight)+`px`;" maxlength="50" cols="10">' + folderName + '</textarea>');
  $('textarea').focus();
  $('textarea').select();
  $('textarea').on('focusout', function(event) {
    renameFolder()
  });
  $("textarea").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
      renameFolder();
    }
  });

});
```

See in playground: https://jsfiddle.net/denisstukalov/espvc8t4/1/#&togetherjs=5mdJ3oeu1y